# I deleted /devel_themer folder now my website reports an error

Tags: debugging

`devel_themer` folder of my website that was in `public_html` had about 500MB size so I deleted this folder. now when I log in to administrative account it reports this error :

`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/my_web_site/public_html/sites/all/modules/devel_themer/devel_themer.module on line 342`

now what shall I do ?

Comment: have you deleted after uninstall ?

Comment: Increase the execution time at your php.ini file & then check. Make it 120

Comment: @Bala I didn't uninstall it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a [known bug](https://drupal.org/node/327512) in a development version of a module. To participate in work on these bugs, join the issue thread on Drupal.org

Comment: You have to disable the module first and then uninstall it and then delete the folder, otherwise you will get error from the module, because it present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I know its answered in comment, but for others who land here.

Increasing the execution time in php.ini can solve this. An ideal value would be `120`.

If it doesn't solve the problem we might need to disable and uninstall the module and fix the problem. Ofcourse you can install it back after things are fixed.

**If you can access the admin page:**

1. Disable the module.
2. Uninstall the module from the uninstall tab in modules page and delete the module folder.
3. Clear the site cache if required.

**If you can't access the admin page:**

1. Delete the module folder.
2. Run update.php

If you were not logged in at the time of the error you will have problem accessing the update.php, then you will have to either use drush the command `drush updatedb` or temporarily enable access to update.php by changing settings.php file.

If you had drush, you an also consider disabling the module with it.

Line to change:

```
$update_free_access = FALSE;
```